# jQuery - When I send a message in chat application, it appends [x] each time

Tags: jquery, html, append, prepend

I've started coding a chat application with `PHP`, `jQuery` and `HTML5`. I have got in a little trouble.
When I send a message, it appends `[x]` every time before the name even if there is an `[x]` or not already.

[A screenshot from the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdTJt.png)

[A screenshot from the JS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQeDj.png)

A piece of HTML codes:

```html
<table id="mt" border="0" style="width:100%">
  <tr id="-1" class="list-group" style="box-shadow:none;margin-bottom:0;">
    <td class="list-group-item" style="border-radius:0;border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #DDD">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading text-center">Example Sticky Message</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text text-center">
        You may add your announcements and requests here. You may edit here in the admin panel.
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="10" class="list-group" style="box-shadow:none;margin-bottom:0;">
    <td class="list-group-item nth" style="border-radius:0;border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #DDD">
      <div class="list-group-item-text">
        <div class="postedIn">21/01/16 12:04 AM</div>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="dm" onclick="delmess($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'))">[x]</a>&nbsp;<b class="usr mem_admin">Admin</b>:
        Bu mesaj örnek bir gönderidir. Mesaj Admin tarafından yollanmıştır.
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="9" class="list-group" style="box-shadow:none;margin-bottom:0;">
    <td class="list-group-item nth" style="border-radius:0;border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #DDD">
      <div class="list-group-item-text">
        <div class="postedIn">21/01/16 12:04 AM</div>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="dm" onclick="delmess($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'))">[x]</a><a href="javascript:;" id="dm" onclick="delmess($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'))">[x]</a>&nbsp;<b class="usr mem_admin">Admin</b>:
        Bu mesaj örnek bir gönderidir. Mesaj Admin tarafından yollanmıştır.
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want my JS code to check if there is an `[x]` before the name. If not, add `[x]` there; if there is, pass it and continue for all the other with `b` tags.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with a class for the `x` mark? You can add that class to every div you add (or any other tag u use) and then style it with css.

It's quite difficult to answer while not having a minimum piece of HTML code.
Edit1: it's recommended NOT to use the `<b></b>` tag. In HTML5 you have `<strong></strong>`. This does the same thing, but it marks it as important and on the settings, some browsers might "pronounce it" (i.e. for any person who has poor eye sight).

Comment: Why don't you copy-paste it in your post? Just a tip, for future.

Comment: @Berkantİpek, why don't you add the `<b>` dynamically with jQuery and after that, add the [x] marker? This way, you add it RIGHT when you add the answer and you don't have to check anything else.

Comment: I created a function and solved the problem.
`$.fn.isAfter = function(sel){return this.prevAll(sel).length !== 0;}`
And it's the usage of it: `if(!$(this).isAfter("a#dm")){//do something}`

Comment: If that works for you, it's good. But I still recommend NOT to use `<b>` unless it's your last resource.